Hyperbolic space groups
This question is about about $n$-dimensional space groups of $\mathbb R^n$. I am wondering if there is a corresponding list and classification of "hyperbolic space groups" for the hyperbolic space, $\mathbb H^n$. I am interested in the case $n=2,3$. I am interested in "hyperbolic space groups" that leave the orbit space of a point on in hyperbolic space invariant. I’m thinking the orbit space as a lattice structure in hyperbolic space.
References would be appreciated.

What so you mean by "leaving $\mathbb H^n/\Gamma$ invariant"? (It is not a fundamental domain by the way.) The group $\Gamma$ does n9t act on this quotient space.

@MoisheKohan Sorry, I meant it should leave the orbit of a point in hyperbolic space invariant. I am thinking of the orbit space as a crystal structure in the hyperbolic space. I hope that makes sense

Well, but this is an empty assumption, since it always holds. In any case, how much do you know about, say, Fuchsian groups and Teichmuller spaces?

@MoisheKohan I know a bit about Fuchsian group, not so much about Teichmuller spaces. What would be the correct analog of wallpaper groups or space groups in hyperbolic geometry? I'm not sure what I am missing out on.

There are two correct analogues in $H^2$: uniform lattices and general lattices. What do you know about classification of Fuchsian groups (whatever the word "classification" means)?

@MoisheKohan Not much about classification. But I reckon I have to look into it for the purposes of my problem. I am interested in uniform lattices for now. I want to know about general lattices as well.

Here is what I initially had in mind. Let's consider the example of the Euclidean case. Consider $\mathbb R^2$ and the lattice $\mathbb Z^2$. Consider the oribit space $\mathbb Z^2 \cdot (0,0)$. The group of symmetries of this orbit space is the wallpaper group $D_4$, unless I am horribly mistaken. I am interested in analogs of wallpaper groups like $D_4$. Note that both $\mathbb Z^2$ and $D_4$ are discrete subgroups of the Euclidean group but the groups are distinct. One generates a crystal structure and the other is the group of symmetries of the crystal. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I think what you are really asking about are maximal cocompact lattices in the full isometry group of hyperbolic plane. The issue is what the word "classification" means to you. If you want to classify up to isometric conjugation then this is hopeless since you get some rather complicated subset of the moduli space of hyperbolic orbifolds. If you want to classify up to a homeomorphic conjugation then there is a reasonable answer via the orbifold theory.

Ahh, yes. I forgot to mention that I am definitely considering co-compact Fucschian/Kleinian groups. I guess homeomorphic conjugation sounds about right. I essentially want to think of these "hyperbolic space groups" as symmetries of some crystal in $H^2, H^3$ generated by the orbit space of a Fucschian/Kleinian group. As a first pass, I am interested in "hyperbolic space/symmetry groups" associated to uniform hyperbolic tilings. I am interested in other examples of tilings and $H^2, H^3$. Once again, references would be appreciated if you know of any.

Ultimately, I am interested in doing some K-theoretic computations for the problem I have but I guess that's besides the point.

Ok, I will add an answer with some references later on. But, in brief, there is no classification in dimension 3. Even for reflection groups, Andreev's theorem is a closest analogue to a classification, but it converts the problem to one of graph theory.

Sounds good. Thanks.

Here is an answer of sorts.

Uniform lattices (i.e. discrete cocompact subgroups) $\Gamma$ in the full isometry group $Isom(\mathbb H^2)$ of the hyperbolic plane.
Up to topological conjugation, such subgroups are described by topology of their quotient-orbifolds  $\mathcal O= \mathbb H^2/\Gamma$, or, equivalently,
by their signature (in the case of orientation-preserving groups) or Conway symbols.
The signature is easier to describe, it is a tuple $(g; n_1,...,n_k)$ where $g$ is the genus of the orbifold $\mathcal O$ and $n_1,...n_k$ are orders of singular/orbifold points in $\mathcal O$.

For all its faults, Katok's book "Fuchsian Groups" is probably your best option for learning this staff.
Katok, Svetlana, Fuchsian groups, Chicago Lectures in Mathematics. Chicago: The University of Chicago Press,. x, 175 p. (1992). ZBL0753.30001.
For learning about classification of 2-dimensional orbifolds, my favorite reference is
Scott, Peter, The geometries of 3-manifolds, Bull. Lond. Math. Soc. 15, 401-487 (1983). ZBL0561.57001.

The situation in dimension 3 is much more complex. On one hand, Mostow Rigidity Theorem implies
that geometry of every complete finite volume 3-dimensional hyperbolic orbifold is determined by its topology: Isomorphic lattices in $Isom(\mathbb H^3)$ are conjugate in  $Isom(\mathbb H^3)$. It follows that there are only countably many (up to isometric conjugation) lattices in $Isom(\mathbb H^3)$. However, there is not even a conjectural way to assign finitary invariants to compact hyperbolic 3-manifolds/orbifolds, analogously to Conway's symbols. Even in the case of maximal arithmetic lattices (which, in a sense, are rare among all lattices) the complete classification is unclear. See

Maclachlan, Colin; Reid, Alan W., The arithmetic of hyperbolic 3-manifolds, Graduate Texts in Mathematics. 219. New York, NY: Springer. xiii, 463 p. (2003). ZBL1025.57001.
Even in the case of cocompact reflection groups, the finitary invariant describing the group is a certain finite labelled planar graph satisfying certain restrictions; this is the subject of Andreev's theorem, see for instance
Roeder, Roland K. W.; Hubbard, John H.; Dunbar, William D., Andreev’s theorem on hyperbolic polyhedra, Ann. Inst. Fourier 57, No. 3, 825-882 (2007). ZBL1127.51012.
Such a graph can be described by a symmetric matrix with integer entries (the Coxeter matrix).
For further reading see for instance
Bruno Martelli, "An Introduction to Geometric Topology".

Thanks a lot for the response!
